# Subir archivo a servidor remoto en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, archivo

Tengo un proyecto en *Laravel 5.6* alojado en un servidor de mi red local en *Debian 9* y *Server Web Apache*, y desde una computadora de mi red quiero subir un achivo *Excel* para después importar sus datos.

Mi vista es esta:

```
<div class="card-body">
        {!! Form::open(['route'=>'import','method'=>'POST', 'accept-charset'=>'UTF-8', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}

          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >

            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">Ã—</a>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            @include('flash::message')

             <input type="file" name="archivo" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-smb btn-success">Importar Archivo</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

... y mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
class ExcelController extends Controller
{

          public function index()
           {
            return view('excel.import');
           }

          public function import(Request $request)
           {

            $request->validate(['archivo'=>'required|mimes:xls,xlsx']);

            $archivo=$request->file('archivo');

            $nombre_original=$archivo->getClientOriginalName();

            \Storage::disk('importes')->put($nombre_original, \File::get($archivo));

            \Flash::info('Los datos se han importado')->important();

            return redirect()->route('excel.import');

       }
}
```

Solo puse la parte en la que me debe guardar el archivo que debe ser en **Storage/importes/archivo.xlsx**, lo cual tengo configurado en **config/filesystems.php** de la siguiente manera:

```
'importes' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('importes'),
    ],
```

El caso es que cuando intento subir el archivo no reconoce el mismo y me sale el siquiente mensaje:

> El campo archivo falló al subir

No sé si es un problema de permiso porque en el servidor local sí funciona perfectamente, pero desde una computadora de la red **no**.

Esta es la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable `$archivo` seguramente está vacia, no sé como arreglar esto y he buscado pero no encuentro respuestas.

Comment: Hermanos ya resolví el problema, en el controller desactivé la validación del fichero excel, entonces me dió realmente cual era el error. Era un problema en php.ini, con el open_basedir, que estaba activado para una dirección específica, lo desactivé y todo resuelto. Gracias

Comment: no se marcarla como resuelta